# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I know this is very common question on stack overflow I tried few of them but its not working in my scenario .

My CollectionController looks like this .

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Middleware\Role;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\User;
use App\Invoice;
use Session;
use Validator;


    class CollectionController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return Response
         */

      public function __construct(){

        $this->middleware('role:collector'); // replace 'collector' with whatever role you need.
    }


      public function getHome(){

          $empid= Auth::user()->empid;
          $invoice = Invoice::where('Status','=',1)->orderBy('Id', 'desc')->get();


        return View('collectionmodule/home')->with(array('invoices'=>$invoice));

     }

       public function getPayment(){

    dd('sssss');
             $id =$invoiceid;
             $invoice = Invoice::where('Id','=',$id)->payments()->comments()->get();

             return View('collectionmodule/payment')->with(array('invoice'=>$id));

     }




        }
```

My Routes for this Class is as follow

```
Route::controller('collection/home','CollectionController');
Route::controller('collection/payment','CollectionController');
```

I am getting following error

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

None of the routes are working can any one help me out

I tried with

```
http://localhost:8000/collection/home/

and 

http://localhost:8000/collection/payment
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to pass method name in route. like below : 
Route::controller('collection/home','CollectionController@index');
Route::controller('collection/payment','CollectionController@payment');

Comment: @LaljiNakum I got my answers I am using Implicit way so I have to assign just one route like this

`Route::controller('collection','CollectionController'); `  its working fine now , Btw do you have anyidea how I will call a model which has one to many relationship ??

Comment: Hey Vikram, it would be best if you post your answer here for future references for others.

Comment: @BharatGeleda yes I am gonna Post it now .

Comment: please have a look at this answer it may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53943911/5068530

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well It was pretty simple

In Implicit call

I should define the route only once

```
Route::controller('collection','CollectionController');
```

so now in url collection/home if being parsed then laravel will automatically call
getHome() function

Answer (score 5):

You have to define only one time the route:

```
Route::controller('collection','CollectionController');
```

And then you can go to the routes you declare in functions name of the controller.

Example:

get**Home**. The route will be collection/home

get**Payments**. The route will be collection/payments

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the exact same exception message in laravel 5.4.10 and after wasting around 2 hours I found out that routes.php has been removed in 5.3 onward versions and just creating file is not enough. We need to include file in RouteServiceProvider.php file inside "map" function.
Adding below line inside **map** function resolved the issue for me :

```
require app_path('Http/routes.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most common exception.

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php
```

And it is quite easy to understand. You can dupe it if you misspell the route name.
It may be `aricles` instead of `articles` and things like that.

Try

```
php artisan route:list
```

And check if all the route names are OK.

Answer (score 0):

Check The Name Of The route,

whether it is capital or small.

Example-> If Folder name is Testing and view name is contact.

If You Write -> localhost/testing/contact, then it is an error because folder name i.e Testing and you have written small t i.e testing.

So you have to write -> localhost/Testing/contact.

And error is solved.