# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.1

I added the following routes in `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});

Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
    return 'User '.$id;
});

Route::post('foo/bar', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});

Route::put('foo/bar', function () {
 //
});

Route::delete('foo/bar', function () {
   //
});
```

And I am getting this error when I browse to `/laravel/user/5/`

> **Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.**
>
> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:1) in
>   RouteCollection.php line 161.2) at
>   RouteCollection-match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 533 at
>   Router-findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 512.

and a bunch of other errors.

Is anything wrong in my route configuration?

Comment: Why are you accessing it `/laravel/user/5/` instead of just `/user/5/`?

Comment: sorry, not /laravel/user/5/ but i only enter " /user/5" in browser.but however all error are same as .....previously

Comment: what's the environment and OS you are using for this project like apache on windows, homestead? If you are using apache on Windows or Linux, turn on the apache rewrite module and set allowoverride all

Comment: my problem was in the virtual server definition where I have defined in the laravel folder as document root in the apache virtual server setup file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is because when  installed laravel through command promot i ran "composer create-project laravel/laravel –-prefer-dist" as the document suggest.

so actually correct command is "composer create-project laravel/laravel yourProjectName"

Comment: one more suggestion to follow syntax:    composer create-project laravel/laravel {project-name} version_of_laravel --prefer-dist

Answer (score 0):

my problem was in the virtual server definition where I have defined in the laravel folder as document root in the apache virtual server setup file,

I was getting the error while accessing

```
localhost:9000/laravel/api/courselist
```

once I changed it to

```
 localhost:9000/api/courselist
```

I started getting the proper response